# Relation between $H^i_I(-)$ and $H^i_J(-)$ when $I\subset J$

Tags: commutative-algebra, homology-cohomology

What is the relation between $H^i_I(-)$ and $H^i_J(-)$ (cohomological functors) when $I\subset J$ are ideals of a (local) noetherian ring?

Comment: In general I'd say that none.